# Valores dos atributos de um objeto duplicados

Tags: php

Estou com o seguinte problema, tenho uma classe chamada `Cliente` com vários atributos e uma classe chamada `DAO_Cliente` que retorna um determinado cliente (`MySQL`). O problema é quando eu tento colocar os valores nos atributos desse objeto, ou seja, quando eu seto o `$id` e o `$nome` (somente) por exemplo todos os atributos ficam com valor do `NOME`, assim como se eu setar o atributo `$telefone1` novamente todos os atributos ficaram com o valor do `TELEFONE`. Estou usando o **php4**.

Segue abaixo a estrutura das classes:

Classe `Cliente`:

```
<?php
    include_once "endereco.php";

    class Cliente{
        public $id;
        public $nome;
        public $dataNasc;
        public $cpf;
        public $identidade;
        public $oEndereco;
        public $telefone1;
        public $telefone2;
        public $referencia;
        public $status;
        public $inscricaoEstadual;
        public $celular;
        public $email;
        public $dataVencimento;
        public $dataVisitaTecnica;
        public $valorMensalidade;
        public $regimeTributario;
        public $observacao;
        public $qtdeEcf;
        public $modelo;
        public $possuiNFe;

        function __construct() {
            $id = 0;
            $nome = '';
            $dataNasc = 0;
            $cpf = '';
            $identidade = '';
            $oEndereco = new Endereco();
            $telefone1 = '';
            $telefone2 = '';
            $referencia = '';
            $status = '';
            $inscricaoEstadual = '';
            $celular = '';
            $email = '';
            $dataVencimento = 0;
            $dataVisitaTecnica = 0;
            $valorMensalidade = 0;
            $regimeTributario = '';
            $observacao = '';
            $qtdeEcf = 0;
            $modelo = '';
            $possuiNFe = '';
        }
    }
?>
```

Classe `Dao_Cliente`:

```
    <?php
    include_once "../conexao.php";
    include_once "../model/cliente.php";

    class DAO_Cliente{
        public function consultar($lcodCli){
            $lconexao = conexao::getInstance();
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM CLIENTES c WHERE c.codigo_cli = '".$lcodCli."'";
      $lconexao->$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("erro de consulta");        
      if ($consulta = mysql_fetch_array($lconexao->$result)){
        $auxCliente = new Cliente();
        $auxCliente->$id = $consulta[CODIGO_CLI];
        $auxCliente->$nome = $consulta[NOME];
        $auxCliente->$dataNasc = $consulta[NASCIMENTO];
        $auxCliente->$cpf = $consulta[CPF];
        $auxCliente->$identidade = $consulta[IDENTIDADE];
        $auxCliente->oEndereco->$logradouro = $consulta[ENDERECO];
        $auxCliente->oEndereco->$cep = $consulta[CEP];
        $auxCliente->oEndereco->$bairro = $consulta[BAIRRO];
        $auxCliente->oEndereco->$cidade = $consulta[CIDADE];
        $auxCliente->$telefone1 = $consulta[TELEFONE1];
        $auxCliente->$telefone2 = $consulta[TELEFONE2];
        $auxCliente->$referencia = $consulta[REFERENCIA];
        $auxCliente->$status = $consulta[STATUS];
        $auxCliente->$inscricaoEstadual = $consulta[Inscricao_Estadual];
        $auxCliente->$celular = $consulta[Celular];
        $auxCliente->$email = $consulta[Email];
        $auxCliente->$dataVencimento = $consulta[Dvencimento];
        $auxCliente->$dataVisitaTecnica = $consulta[DVisitaTecn];
        $auxCliente->$valorMensalidade = $consulta[Valor_da_mensalidade];
        $auxCliente->$regimeTributario = $consulta[Regime_tributario];
        $auxCliente->$observacao = $consulta[Observacao];
        $auxCliente->$qtdeEcf = $consulta[QUANT_ECFs_INST];
        $auxCliente->$modelo = $consulta[Modelo];
        $auxCliente->$possuiNFe = $consulta[NFe];

        mysql_free_result($lconexao->$result); 

                return $auxCliente;
      }

      return null;

    }
?>
```

E aqui a chamada onde os valores dos atributos estão duplcicados:

```
if ($auxCliente != null){
      echo $auxCliente->$id." - ".$auxCliente->$nome." - ".$auxCliente->$dataNasc." - ".$auxCliente->$cpf." - ".$auxCliente->$identidade." - ".$auxCliente->oEndereco->$logradouro." - ".$auxCliente->oEndereco->$bairro." - ".$auxCliente->oEndereco->$cep." - ".$auxCliente->oEndereco->$cidade." - ".$auxCliente->$telefone1." - ".$auxCliente->$telefone2." - ".$auxCliente->$referencia." - ".$auxCliente->$status." - ".$auxCliente->$inscricaoEstadual." - ".$auxCliente->$celular." - ".$auxCliente->$email." - ".$auxCliente->$dataVencimento." - ".$auxCliente->$dataVisitaTecnica." - ".$auxCliente->$valorMensalidade." - ".$auxCliente->$regimeTributario." - ".$auxCliente->$observacao." - ".$auxCliente->$qtdeEcf." - ".$auxCliente->$modelo." - ".$auxCliente->$possuiNFe;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugiro que adicione aspas simples em todos os acessos do array do banco e também atribua os valores nas propriedades do objeto cliente.

Mude as ocorrências de:

```
$auxCliente->$id = $consulta[CODIGO_CLI];
```

Para

```
$auxCliente->id = $consulta['CODIGO_CLI'];

------------^               ^----------^
cifrão removido             aspas adicionadas
```

Ao fazer um teste parcial foi retornado os seguintes erros/warnings:

> Undefined variable: id in

e

> Cannot access empty property in

[phpfiddle - exemplo dos erros.](https://phpfiddle.org/main/code/pp4k-weu7)

O mesmo vale para iniciar os atributos no construtor, da forma que está você está basicamente criando um monte de variaveis que perderam o valor após o construtor ser invocado.

Mude:

```
function __construct() {
   $id = 0;
```

Para:

```
function __construct() {
   $this->id = 0;
```

Comment: Eu retirei as aspas simples dos acessos do array do banco de dados justamente para testar, mas com ou sem aspas o erro persiste...

Comment: @Robson Removeu o cifrão?

Comment: Sim, do jeito que você disse, só que agora os atributos do objeto Cliente não possuem mais valor nenhum! Já no objeto Endereço (dentro de Cliente) os valores do atributo logradouro estão duplicados! Muito estranho

Comment: Bom, o que eu percebi foi que se eu tirar o cifrão os valores dos atributos tipo que não atribuem, perdem os valores...

Comment: Qual vesão do php está usando?

Comment: Infelizmente a versão 4

Comment: Aaaaa por isso... vou altera a resposta, ela é voltada para o php5.

Comment: Deu certo agora?

Comment: Não precisa! Já foi resolvido! Muito obrigado rray. O problema estava justamente no cifrão, tanto na atribuição $auxCliente->id = $consulta['CODIGO_CLI']; quanto na chamada $auxCliente->id. Como sou novo em php acho que acabei me confundindo e chamando sempre $atributo